# Will SQL Server transactional replication guarantee the insert order in subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication

We are using SQL Server 2008 and trying to use transaction replication to reduce the pressure on DB. but we have one concern which is whether it can guarantee the same execution order between publisher and subscriber?

for example, if we run following insert in publisher DB

```
insert into Table A
insert into Table B
```

will these 2 insert be executed in the same order in subscriber DB

Comment: since it replicates the transactions exactly as they happened, I would expect so yes. It would be a pretty useless feature if it didn't, to be honest, since data integrity would be out of the window (and some code would just fail).

Comment: Yes, but only if both tables are part of the same publication. There is no intrinsic order or synchronization between different publications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. In transactional replication, Log Reader Agent is responsible for reading the log file and transfer data which are marked for replication from publication database to distribution database. To do this, Log Reader Agent scans the Log file. Log Reader Agent is a continuous job and there is no way that it will skip some transactions and transfer some other transaction of the same table to the distributor.

On the other hand, Replication Distribution Agent transfers transactions from Distributor database to Subscriber databases. This should also happen in the order the transactions are written to the Distributor because if it is not the case there is no consistency of data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rows will be inserted in the same order if both tables are in the same publication.
Log reader agent will read the data from transaction log in the order it was written and push to distribution database.
from there distribution agent will read and apply the commands in the same order to subscriber database.